# Request halts in rails server. Happens randomly, can't regenerate the issue on purpose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

So I have a rails app running on apache2 - passenger. Sometimes (usually first request after the server goes into stand by/sleep mode) the server does not respond to a request. On checking the apache logs, I see that request got halted

```
I, [2015-05-14T08:34:57.867684 #29618]  INFO -- : Started POST "/v1/reply" for X.X.X.X at 2015-05-14 08:34:57 +0000
```

After the Started POST there are no log entries. What can be going wrong? I am going mad over this issue.

Using Ruby 2.2, Rails 4.0, Apache2, Passenger 4.0.50. I was previously using the latest version of passenger but then reverted to an old version to see if this fixes the issue. But no luck.

Comment: Any information in Apache's error.log or Rails' production.log?

Comment: Nothing in apache's error.log. The log posted above is from rail's production.log file

Comment: Also, if i refresh the page multiple times, it starts working.

Comment: So it turns out that the server just hangs for a while on a request and then after few mins starts again and then all the requests are processed. This would repeat after few hours again :( Totally going mad about it.

Comment: How about increasing the PassengerPoolIdleTime to 0, as suggested in an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581737/my-passenger-powered-rails-app-sometimes-needs-a-long-time-to-load

Comment: Well, nothing worked and it looks like some issue with the server (Google Compute Engine). As a desperate measure, I moved my app to AWS with same config and its working perfectly. Still not sure what was the root cause :(